# Событие удаления текста из текстового поля?

Tags: jquery

Какое событие применить из Jquery, чтобы отследить изменение текста в текстовом поле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый лучший способ - событие input. Оно даже реагирует на вставку из буфера обмена

```
$('input[type=text]').on('input', function() {
   // ваш код
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change

Answer (score 0):

keypress, keyup, keydown, paste